# Why is the validation of a hidden field in a kendo.ui javascript template not working when initialized over template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, kendo-ui

On my page the content is created on the client side using this kendo.ui template:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="BerichtElementTemplate-Tabelle">
    <div class="bericht-element">
        <input type="hidden" name="Elemente[#= Index #].Art" value="@BerichtElementArten.Tabelle" />
        <label for="Elemente[#= Index #].TabelleCsv">[[[Tabelle:]]]</label>
        <div class="InputWrapper">
            <input type="hidden" name="Elemente[#= Index #].TabelleCsv" value="#= TabelleCsv#" required data-required-msg="[[[Bitte geben Sie einen Wert ein.]]]" />
            <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="Elemente[#= Index #].TabelleCsv"></span>
            <input type="file" onchange="csvFileInput_OnChange(this)" />
            <div class="csv-preview">[[[Keine Daten vorhanden. Bitte wählen Sie eine CSV-Datei aus.]]]</div>
            <span>[[[Überschrift:]]]</span>
            <input type="text" name="Elemente[#= Index #].TabelleUeberschrift" maxlength="200" class="k-textbox" value="#= TabelleUeberschrift #" />
            <span>[[[Unterschrift:]]]</span>
            <input type="text" name="Elemente[#= Index #].TabelleUnterschrift" maxlength="200" class="k-textbox" value="#= TabelleUnterschrift #" />
        </div>
        <div class="remove-element">
            <img src="/images/delete2.png" title="[[[Entfernen...]]]" onclick="RemoveBerichtElementImage_OnClick(this)" />
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

The data is loaded using the following code:

```
$("#DynamicContentWrapper").append($berichtElementTemplateTabelle({
        Index: @j,
        TabelleCsv: '@Html.Raw(javaScriptSafeCsv)',
        TabelleUeberschrift: '@elem.TabelleUeberschrift',
        TabelleUnterschrift: '@elem.TabelleUnterschrift'
    })
);
```

This works so far. What does not work is the validation of the hidden input field. The validator says that the field is empty, while it is not. I checked it with FireBug.

The odd thing is, that if I change the code to the following:

```
$("#DynamicContentWrapper").append($berichtElementTemplateTabelle({
        Index: @j,
        TabelleCsv: '',
        TabelleUeberschrift: '@elem.TabelleUeberschrift',
        TabelleUnterschrift: '@elem.TabelleUnterschrift'
    })
);
$("[name$='[@j].TabelleCsv']")[0].value = '@Html.Raw(javaScriptSafeCsv)';
```

Which means the value of the hidden field is set after the templated content is added. The validator no longer complains.

Is this a bug in kendo.ui? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. This line:

```
TabelleCsv: '@Html.Raw(javaScriptSafeCsv)',
```

needs to be:

```
TabelleCsv: '@javaScriptSafeCsv',
```

Because the string `javaScriptSafeCsv` may contain quotes or other characters that affect the HTML of the page. While FireBug showed no error, the HTML markup was destroyed by the kendo template that wrote the string as raw HTML into the input field's value attribute.